# Convert string with dollar sign in it to int

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup, request, integer

Hi i am working on a projekt where i need to scrape a site and get a int. The problem is that i get the text with a dollar sign how do i convert it to an int from. Is there anything i can do?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/forus/"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
x = soup.find_all("div", class_="priceValue")
print(x[0].text.strip())
```

Comment: Use `.replace()` to remove the dollar sign. I can't be sure, but in your code it might look something like `print(x[0].text.strip().replace("$", ""))`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though you don't really need to strip() the text in this case but I've left it in anyway (just in case):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/forus/"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
for x in soup.find_all("div", class_="priceValue"):
    print(x.text.strip()[1:])
```

**Output:**

```
0.000354
```

**However:**

Your question mentions converting to *int* which may not be appropriate as the value appears to be a string representation of a floating point number